Schur-Weyl type decomposition for subgroup of $ S_n $
Consider the standard set up for Schur-Weyl duality where each $ g \in GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ acts diagonally on $ (\mathbb{C}^{n})^{\otimes k} $ by $ g^{\otimes k} $, and $ S_k $ acts by permuting the $ k $ tensor factors. These actions obviously commute and we can then decompose
$$
(\mathbb{C}^{n})^{\otimes k}=  \bigoplus_D \pi_{S_k}^D \otimes \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D
$$
where the irreps $ \pi_{S_k}^D $ of $ S_k $ are indexed here by their Young diagrams $ D $. And the $ \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D $ are irreps of $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ again indexed by Young diagram $ D $. Another interesting thing to note is that each $ \pi_{S_k}^D \otimes \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D $ is an isotypic subspace for both $ S_k $ and $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $. Indeed, $ \pi_{S_k}^D \otimes \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D $ is the $ \pi_{S_k}^D $ isotypic subspace for $ S_k $ and is the $ \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D $ isotypic subspace for $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $.
Here is my question: What if we replace $ S_k $ with some subgroup $ \Sigma \subset S_k $? Are we still guaranteed a decomposition
$$
(\mathbb{C}^{n})^{\otimes k}=  \bigoplus_i \pi_{\Sigma}^i \otimes \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^i
$$
where the $ \pi_{\Sigma}^i $ are irreps of $ \Sigma $, and $ \pi_{\Sigma}^i \otimes \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^i $ is the $ \pi_{\Sigma}^i $ isotypic subspace, but now the representations $ \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D $ of $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ are not necessarily irreducible.

Just for my own understanding I'm rewriting the accepted answer given by Kyle Miller below.
\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes k} &\cong \bigoplus_D \pi_{S_k}^D \otimes \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D \\
& \cong \bigoplus_D \left(\bigoplus_i (n^D_i) \pi_\Sigma^i \right) \otimes \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D \\
& \cong \bigoplus_i \pi_\Sigma^i\otimes \left(\bigoplus_D (n^D_i) \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D\right) \\
\end{align*}
In other words Kyle shows that the reducible $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $  representation $ \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^i $ I'm looking for is exactly given in terms of $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ irreps and multiplicity as
$$
\rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^i= \bigoplus_D (n^D_i) \rho_{GL(n,\mathbb{C})}^D
$$
where $ n^D_i $ is the multiplicity of the $ i $th irrep of $ \Sigma $ in the restriction to $ \Sigma $ of the $ D $ irrep of $ S_k $. And we should not forget that the sum over $ D $ is only over Young diagrams with $ k $ boxes and at most $ n $ rows, as is always the case for Schur-Weyl duality.

Do you mean to say "where the $\pi^i_k$ are irreps of $\Sigma$" rather than "... of $S_k$"? Because otherwise you can use the Schur-Weyl decomposition.

@KyleMiller ah yes thank you! fixed the typo now

Yes. The idea is that when you restrict to the subgroup $\Sigma\subset S_k$, any given irreducible representation $\pi^D_k$ of $S_n$ splits into irreducible representations of $\Sigma$ as
$$ \pi^D_k \approx \bigoplus_i (\pi_\Sigma^i)^{\oplus n^D_i} $$
where $\{\pi^i_\Sigma\}_i$ is the family of irreducible representations of $\Sigma$ and each $n^D_i$ coefficient gives the multiplicity of $\pi_\Sigma^i$ in $\operatorname{Res}^{S_k}_\Sigma \pi_k^D$.
Then, using distributivity of tensor products over direct sums,
\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes k} &\approx \bigoplus_D \pi_k^D\otimes \rho_k^D \\
& \approx \bigoplus_D \left(\bigoplus_i (\pi_\Sigma^i)^{\oplus n^D_i}\right)\otimes \rho_k^D \\
& \approx \bigoplus_i \pi_\Sigma^i\otimes \left(\bigoplus_D(\rho_k^D)^{\oplus n^D_i}\right) \\
\end{align*}
Thus, not only do we see what "$\rho_k^i$" is in the decomposition (using your notation), but we can also see to what degree it fails to be an irreducible representation.
You might want to work out what happens in an example like $S_3\subset S_4$, since it's not so hard to calculate all the multiplicities. Then, depending on how big $n$ is, some of these $\rho_k^D$ representations might be zero, so there's a chance to see an irreducible $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ representation. If I got this right, this only happens in this case for $n=1$ and $n=3$.

I'm concerned that there is something not quite right about this answer. For example consider the cyclic group $ C_6 \subset S_6 $. And consider the trivial rep of $ C_6 $. The only irrep of $ S_6 $ that restricts to the trivial rep of $ C_6 $ is the trivial rep of $ S_6 $. But the trivial rep of $ S_6 $ only corresponds to a single copy of the 7 dimensional irrep of $ GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ whereas $  (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 6} $ has actually 14 copies of the trivial rep of $ C_6 $ if I am counting correctly. Something seems fishy about the $ 14 $ versus the $ 7 $ but I don't know what

@IanGershonTeixeira Using the order in the character table on this page, it appears to me that when you restrict to $C_6$, this is the number of trivial representations appearing in each: 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2. Only two irreps of $S_6$ when restricted to $C_6$ don't contain a trivial rep. The 1st, 3rd, 6th, and 7th irreps of $S_6$ can appear in $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 6}$. The GL(2) representations have dimension of 7, 5, 1, and 3, and $1\cdot7+0\cdot5+1\cdot1+2\cdot3=14$, matching your count.

Ok now that I think more about it my claim that the trivial rep of $ S_6 $ is the only irrep whose restriction to $ C_6 $ contains any copies of trivial rep of $ C_6 $ seems wrong. Seems like you're definitely right but how did you get the numbers $ 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2 $ as multiplicity of the $ C_6 $ trivial irrep in the restriction of the $ S_6 $ irreps of dimensions $ 1,1,5,5,5,5,9,9,10,10,16 $?

also are you sure you didn't mean 5th irrep of $ S_6 $ rather than the 6th? ( I know they are both 5d irreps and correspond to conjugate partition so a little difficult to tell apart but I think the link you gave lists the irrep for the partition $ 3+3 $ as the 5th irrep whereas the the 6th irrep has three rows and is the partition $ 2+2+2 $.)

@IanGershonTeixeira The tables on that page seem to have the 5th and 6th in different orders... it caused me a lot of confusion why the 5th in the character table corresponded to a dimension-0 GL(2) irrep! The way I calculated the trivial irreps of $C_6$ in each $S_6$ irrep was to sum up the columns corresponding to elements of $C_6$ (with the correct multiplicities, since some $C_6$ elements are conjugate in $S_6$) then divide by 6.

Ok so you find the character for the reducible $ C_6 $ representation given by restriction just by looking directly at the character table with the cycle structures at the link https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S6 and then you are getting the multiplicity of the trivial character by taking an inner product of the two characters. You're right it is pretty confusing that the 6th character in the character table corresponds to the 5th irrep in the table above called "Interpretation as symmetric group" where the Young diagrams are shown.

Clearly you are right that the 5th and 6th irreps in the character table are swapped and displayed as the 6th and 5th irreps, respectively, in the "Interpretation as symmetric group" table above, because otherwise the multiplicity of the trivial rep in the restriction of the $ (3,3) $ irrep is 2 not 1, and then the sum is 15 not 14. But can you explain how you directly determined that the 6th character corresponds to the Young diagram $ (3,3) $ listed 5th in the "Interpretation as symmetric group" table?

@IanGershonTeixeira It was from calculating the dimensions of the corresponding GL(2) representations from the characters and seeing which ones were nonzero. Nonzero meant that the Young diagram had no more than two rows, and from there I could deduce which was which. (There are also methods to calculate characters from the Young diagram. I just found https://www.jgibson.id.au/articles/characters/ which also shows characters per Young diagram. $s[3^2]$ there corresponds to row six of groupprops.)

Perfect! The link labels every character of $ S_k $ directly by its Young diagram. And we are only interested in Young diagrams with at most two rows since we are doing this for $ GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ and for a Young diagram with $ b_1 $ boxes in the first row and $ b_2 $ boxes in the second row the dimension of the corresponding $ GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ irrep is $ b_1-b_2+1 $. To compute the branching one just needs to know which columns of the character table are for the cycle types found in $ C_n $ and cycle types are also labelled at the Gibson link (whereas GAP does not label so explicitly).

Multiplying by the sign irrep is equivalent to taking the transpose of the Young diagram and for the $ GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ case there can be max 2 rows so for $ k>2 $ we can never allow a proper transpose so we aren't going to use any characters that take negative values on cycle type $ (12) $. That fact alone shows that you were correct in choosing the 6th and not the 5th irrep in the character table here https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S6 Anyway thanks so much this has all been super helpful I learned alot!
